# How to use this cURL POST Request in Java? (Spotify API)

Tags: java, curl, post, spotify

I need help making a cURL POST Request (to the Spotify API) in Java. I have interpreted my solution out of [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-curl).

So based on that I've tryed the following:

```java
String command = "curl -X 'POST' -H 'Authorization: Basic Base64TokenHere' -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'";
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            process.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String output;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(output);
            }
            br.close();

            System.out.println(response.toString())

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It seems to work, however I'm not getting a response, and yes the cURL Command itself works.

If you have any idea on why this isn't providing any output like it does normally, please tell me.

This is what the output should look like, if you aren't familiar with the Spotify API:

```json
{
   "access_token": "NgCXRKc...MzYjw",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "expires_in": 3600,
}
```

If there is an alternative to my solution above that I should use instead provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nevermind I fixed it myself. Instead of trying to make a direct cURL-Request from Java I used an URLConnection and basically transformed everything to that.

```java
try {
        URL url = new URL("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
        URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
        urlc.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic Base64TokenHere");

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlc.getOutputStream());

        writer.write("grant_type=client_credentials");
        writer.flush();

        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(urlc.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        }

        writer.close();
        reader.close();

} catch (IOException ioException) {
  ioException.printStackTrace();
}
```